# iframe embedded video on samsung smart tv

Tags: html, html5-video, samsung-smart-tv

In a local website I'm coding I have the following to embed a video stream:

```
<iframe width="450" height="350" src="https://www.streamago.tv/channel/810/default/iframe/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

My Samsung smart-tv ES5500's default web browser, however, doesn't seem to like this, and only shows a black rectangle. Is there a way to work this around?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. This is done by Samsung for security issues, as abuse could create Cross Site Forgery Requests.

Looking at the page you posted (nice one for Rai News!) you could capture the screen on a remote server and [Stream Rai News 24](http://live.smoothstreaming.rai.it/live/218350_218351/rai9.isml/Manifest)